# Does Pyspark Pandas support Pandas pct_change function?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I saw that `pct_change` function is partially implemented with the missing of some parameters.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/supported_pandas_api.html

Yet, when I tried

```
data_pd = data.toPandas
data_pd.pct_change()
```

, there was `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pct_change'`

I want to know whether it is not implemented yet. If no, what is the correct way to use `pct_change` function in pyspark pandas API? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a chat with @Saideep Arikontham, we find that `pandas_api()` can solve the problem.

```
    #Covert Spark Dataframe to Spark Pandas Dataframe 
    data_pd = data.pandas_api()

    data_pd.pct_change()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `pct_change()` function on **Pyspark pandas Dataframe** or **Pyspark pandas Series**. The error, however, indicates that the pct_change() has been used on a `function` object.

The following is a demonstration of how you can use this function.

- **Using Pyspark pandas Dataframe:**

```
from pyspark import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([[10, 18, 11], [20, 15, 8], [30, 20, 3]])
print(type(df))
print(df.pct_change())
```

[image]

- **Using Pyspark pandas Series:**

```
data = pandas.Series([90, 91, 85], index=[2, 4, 1])
print(type(data))
print(data.pct_change())
```

[image]

***UPDATE:***

- The error occurs because, using `DataFrame.toPandas` is different from `DataFrame.toPandas()`.
- In this case, when you use `data.toPandas` it returns an object of type **`method`**. When you try to use `pct_change()` on this object, it is giving error.

[image]

- Using `DataFrame.toPandas()` would return a **DataFrame** object on which you can use `pct_change()`. So modify the code as following to achieve the requirement.

```
data_pd = data.toPandas()
print(type(data_pd))

op = data_pd.pct_change()
print(op)
```

[image]

Comment: Here is my code:  I tried to convert spark dataframe to pandas `data_pd = data.toPandas`.  After that, I tried `data_pd.pct_change()`. However, the `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pct_change'` comes out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Databricks told me that `toPandas() `was deprecated and it suggested me to use `toPandas`. If I use `toPandas()` instead of `toPandas`, the task will fail. [https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D58Y00008uAbi6SAC](https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D58Y00008uAbi6SAC)

Comment: Are you getting the same warning message as in the link that you provided?

Comment: I asked the question in the Databricks community. I realized that `toPanads` could finish the task while `toPandas()` could not. That's why I cannot use `toPandas()` to solve the `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pct_change'` .

Comment: Is `to_pandas_on_spark()` not working? And can you please provide Databricks runtime version (is it 10.4 LTS)?

Comment: `to_pandas_on_spark()` also doesn't work. Cluster Model: Standard. Runtime version: 11.0(Includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12). Worker Type: Standard_DS3_V2.

Comment: Try using `data_pd = data.pandas_api()`. This will return `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame` object. Now you can use pct_change() on this `data_pd`

Comment: If I use to_pandas_on_spark(), there will be 1 warning message and 1 error message:
 `/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:3407: FutureWarning: DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark is deprecated. Use DataFrame.pandas_api instead.

warnings.warn(`
 

`SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 21.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 21.0 (TID 24) (10.139.64.4 executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 176959 ms`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246662/discussion-between-saideeparikontham-mt-and-flinty).